# If RNA transcription is 5' end to 3' end, what is the directionality of the promoter for?

Tags: transcription, mrna

I am confused. If RNA transcription always grows from the 5' end to the 3' end, what does the direction of the promoter do for the mRNA transcribed?

From what i understand the RNA polymerase always extends the mRNA from the 5' end to the 3' end. Yet promoter sequences define the direction of transcription?

Which one is correct? Does mRNA transcription always extend from 5' to 3'? Or does the promoter dictate the direction in which the RNA polymerase extends mRNA?

Or it the truth somewhere in between?

Comment: Can you explain your thinking a bit further to focus the problem?

Comment: Think! DNA is double-stranded. What exactly do you understand in molecular terms by the statement "(the) promoter sequences define the direction of transcription"? Draw yourself a diagram.

Comment: Ok Sir, so there are 2 strands of DNA, so depending on the direction of the promoter, either one of the strands of DNA becomes the coding template (get transcribed)?
Is that correct?

Comment: I’ve just seen your comment. You need to address me as @david so I am alerted to your reply to me. (I don’t have to do the same as I am commenting on your post.) In answer to your query, that’s almost right. But it’s not only the DNA strand that is different, it’s its location or direction relative to that of the promoter.